# Changing the locale is modifying the text dimensions of my app

Tags: java, android, locale

I'm trying to change the language on my Android app and I'm using this code:

```
String languageToLoad  = "en";
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

I've created different `values` directories (`\values-fr`, `\values-it`, etc.) where I put my `string.xml` files.

Changing the language works normally, but the problem is that it's changing text dimensions in my app (text sizes on textviews, menu, dialogs, edittexts, buttons...basically in all my app).

Removing the block code that changes the locale, the app layout gets back to normal. Is the `getDisplayMetrics()` creating the problem?

I'm using styles for some of the texts:

```
<style name="title_font">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#095080</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">26sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

And some example of textviews:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        style="@style/title_font"
        android:text="@string/login_title" />

<TextView
      android:id="@+id/label_user"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
      android:text="@string/user_label"
      android:layout_below="@+id/login"/>
```

Can you tell me why is this happening and how to solve it?
If you need any additional information, please ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few hours of searching, I found the solution in a comment here: [Android changing language configuration messes up layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289060/android-changing-language-configuration-messes-up-layout)

Basically you have to replace

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
```

with

```
Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
```

This way, you don't create a new configuration, but only modifying the existing one.